# Name Not Getting Updated in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to update Box Name in Pixel Tracking Tab see First Image.

**Expected Result :**
After Editing, Updated Name should be displayed on Pixel Tracking tab

**Actual Result**
After Editing, Name is not updated and redirect to Countdown tab

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNiQL.png)

[Edit Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXIEt.png)

[After Click on Update Button, page should automatically redirect to Pixel Tracking Tab, but unfortunately it goes to CountDown Tab also name is not getting updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nszxd.png)

[HTML Image for Update Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWX9S.png)

**Code For Edit Button Click on Pixel Tab**

```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='tbl_list_pixels_js']/div[2]/table/tbody/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[4]/i")));
   WebElement edit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='tbl_list_pixels_js']/div[2]/table/tbody/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[4]/i"));
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", edit);
```

**Code for Click on Save**

```
     new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("edit_pixel_tracking_redirect_url"))).sendKeys("http://www.google.com");
WebElement Save_pt = driver.findElement(By.id("btnEditCampaign"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Save_pt);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Ok Sure I will go through How to Ask page for details.